# Android Java Repeat string x times

Tags: java, android, string

I want to repeat a string X times in Android Java.

This, as I understand it, is not a good option:

```
StringUtils.repeat("abc", 50);
```

Because it would require

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils; // External libary --- cannot use
```

So what is the best way to repeat a string X times for Android in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own `StringUtils` class which has a `repeat` function that does that, for example:

```
public class StringUtils{
     public static String repeat(String val, int count){
          StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(val.length() * count);
          while (count-- > 0) {
               buf.append(val);
          }
          return buf.toString();
     }
}
```

Comment: Probably don't want to do this, because since Strings are immutable that "ret += val" will be creating new string objects every time. It's better to use something like a stringbuilder when there's a variable number of strings that would need to be built along the way.

Comment: Very bad example. Don't use `String += String`. **Never** use `String += String` in a loop. Use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the suggestions, I will change my example to use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: A couple of syntax errors ... String str instead of String val and new StringBuilder(count) instead of StringBuilder(outputLength).  But otherwise, looks good.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, you can reduce your variable count by replacing `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)` with `for (;count >= 0; count--)`.

Comment: The edits you have made to this make it very solid, especially since it takes the length of the input string now into consideration.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a stringbuilder and a regular loop. Inside the loop, append the string to the stringbuilder, and then after the loop print the string from the builder.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    stringBuilder.append("xyz");
}
String resultString = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: Could you provide an example?